# Arbitrarily querying the count from multiple pivot? tables

Tags: sql

I'm stuck trying to figure out how combine these tables in such a way that I can arbitrarily query for the total count given the query criteria.

Access Patterns:

Get a single count for a single field (just use the subtotals table)

Get a count with criteria that fully matches a given category (just query the single category)

Get a count for criteria that requires using multiple categories (this is where I'm stuck)

I'm stuck at how do I get the correct count using a generic query, and I'm not sure if it's even possible.

For example trying to query for the count of

EmployeeRole: Developer

Age: 25

BossName: John

Table: CategoryA

```
EmployeeRole    | Gender     | Age          | Count      |
----------------------------------------------------------
Developer       | Male       | 25           | 5          |
Project Manager | Male       | 32           | 2          |
...
```

Table: CategoryB

```
EmployeeRole    | Gender     | Ethnicity    | Count      |
----------------------------------------------------------
Developer       | Male       | White        | 2          |
Project Manager | Male       | Indian       | 3          |
...
```

Table: CategoryC

```
EmployeeRole    | BossName   | Count |
--------------------------------------
Developer       | John       |   3   |
Project Manager | Robert     |   4   | 
...
```

Table: CategoryC

```
EmployeeRole    | OfficeName | Count |
--------------------------------------
Developer       | Downtown   |   20  |
Project Manager | Rural      |   3   | 
...
```

Also have access to a list of subtotal tables for each field value.

i.e for EmployeeRole Developer we have a table / row with the total amount of developers

I've tried to full join but that will end up with the count for each category in the list and not sure how to aggregate and derive the real count.

Comment: Hi - it’s really unclear, to me, what you are trying to achieve and the sources you are dealing with. You seem to have multiple, similar, tables which already contain counts - which is an odd design. Where is this data ultimately coming from and can’t you just query those sources rather than these pre-aggregated tables? Can you also update your question to show the result you are trying to achieve? BTW I assume the final table should be CategoryD not CategoryC?